# MySQL query problem

Tags: mysql

How can I add the following code example 1 to example 2 without messing up my query.

Example 1

```
INNER JOIN users ON users_articles.user_id = users.user_id
```

Example 2.

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users_articles
INNER JOIN articles_comments ON users_articles.id = articles_comments.article_id
INNER JOIN users ON articles_comments.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE users.active IS NULL
AND users.deletion = 0
ORDER BY articles_comments.date_created DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to join table `users` twice, once for comments, and once for articles? In that case, you need to alias the table. I usually use single- or two-letter aliases for brevity even when I do not double tables, but it is not important.

```
SELECT ...
FROM users_articles UA
INNER JOIN articles_comments AC ON UA.id = AC.article_id
INNER JOIN users UC ON AC.user_id = UC.user_id
  AND UC.active IS NULL
  AND UC.deletion = 0
INNER JOIN users UA ON UA.user_id = users.user_id
  AND UA.active IS NULL
  AND UA.deletion = 0
ORDER BY AC.date_created DESC
LIMIT 50
```

BTW, Don't use `SELECT *`, it is almost always better to list specifically what you want.

**Disclaimer**: I might have misunderstood what you are trying to do; posting a bit of context to your code is usually a good idea. In this case, the table names threw me a bit (if it's what I think it is, I'd've just gone with `users`, `articles` and `comments`).

Comment: I dont want to display articles and its commets where `users.deletion = 1`

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What does it do? What do you want it to do? The code above should also be rejecting deleted users, so I don't quite get your comment about that, either.

Comment: I get this error mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Comment: Okay, there's an error - get `mysqli_error()` before `mysqli_num_rows()` to see what it is.